# Limit Shopify Function to logged in customers only

Tags: shopify

I implemented an automatic discount using the function (product discount API) which applies discounts based on the customer's tags.

For context, this is how it looks in the GraphQL input:

```
query Input {
  cart {
    buyerIdentity {
      customer {
        id
        test: hasAnyTag(tags: ["test"])
      }
    }
    lines {
      merchandise {
        __typename
        ...on ProductVariant {
          id
          product {
            ...
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Everything would be fine, but we discovered that an unauthenticated user can enter the email of a user who meets the criteria and receive the discount (although all information will be sent to a different email, the product will still be discounted).**

The customer object doesn't have a property like "isLoggedIn". Does anyone have any ideas? It was possible to handle this in the Script Editor using simple `if customer`
As an alternative solution, I could enforce login for specific products, but I haven't heard of that being possible.

Forcing all users to log in before proceeding to checkout is a business-level decision that I would prefer to avoid for now.

EDIT:
I have tried checkout validation API and it doesn't solve the issue either

Input:

```
{
  "buyerJourney": {
    "step": "CHECKOUT_INTERACTION"
  },
  "cart": {
    "buyerIdentity": {
      "email": "alksdj@gmail.com",
      "customer": {
        "id": "gid://shopify/Customer/6936468160786",
      }
    },
    "lines": [
      {
        "quantity": 2
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

From Schema:

```
query Input {
  cart {
    buyerIdentity {
      email
      customer {
        id
      }
    }
    lines {
      quantity
    }
  }
}
```

Screenshot as proof:
[image]
[image]

Comment: How is that if you are checking the customer, and they are NOT logged in, that your function returns a customer? You would think that would return nil for a customer ID and you'd happily reject any discounting.

Comment: Exactly, how weird is that? I have double-checked in function logs and I get the ID of the customer that I have entered into email input field in the contact information step.

It turns out I will have to use checkout validation API that is not yet available to merchants. "Lol" is how I feel about this whole situation. So is my client.

Comment: What is your contact information step? I have never heard of that.

Comment: My bad, typing in rush. I mean the first step in the checkout where you provide all contact info, including your email

Comment: Ahh. Such is life then. Not much you can do.

Comment: Did you discover any more to this? You're saying I fill in checkout 100% as me, but as long as I provide an email of the "target" account, I get their discount? Why is that discount a thing? Could not limit that discount to be a one time use, so that that target account uses it once, and then it is done? 

Any, it is amusing to see holes in the new Functions. The more you share here the better! Popcorn! Drama!

Comment: @DavidLazar I have tried the checkout validation API without any luck. Guess I will try to reach out to ShopifyEng :)

Comment: I don't know how I got to the 2nd step with the error, probably cache